# drawing a line inside a node

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to draw a line with a specific length, angle and colour inside a node. I use the following code to draw a circle and something that imitates a line inside a node.

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick, blue, densely dashed] (0,0)  node[red, xshift=.5cm, yshift=0cm]{\large I}  node [xshift=1cm, yshift=0cm, circle, draw,solid, green, fill=green, scale=0.8]{} -- (3,0);
\draw [thick, blue, densely dashed] (0,0)  node[red, xshift=0cm, yshift=1cm]{\Huge -} -- (0,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, with `path picture`s, e.g.

```
path picture={
\draw[blue] (path picture bounding box.west) -- (path picture bounding box.east);
}
```

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [circle, draw,solid, green, fill=green,minimum width=2cm,
path picture={
\draw[blue] (path picture bounding box.west) -- (path picture bounding box.east);
}]{} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you tell me what you have in mind in your example, perhaps I know how to do it.

**UPDATE**: Just for fun: tick marks. I also draw the node on the `background` layer, but of course if I would draw it before the line the outcome would be the same.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,plotmarks}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick, blue, densely dashed] (0,0)  -- (3,0);
\draw [thick, blue, densely dashed] (0,0) -- (0,3);
\foreach \X in {1,2}
{\node[red] (x-\X) at (\X,0){\pgfuseplotmark{|}};
\node[red] (y-\X) at (0,\X){\pgfuseplotmark{-}};}
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node [circle, draw,solid, green, fill=green, scale=0.8]
at (x-1){};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to add tick marks along a line

Comment: I have just put the code of drawing a circle inside a node as an example that might be edited.

Comment: @Hany OK I added one possible way of adding tick marks. Of course, there are plenty more elegant solutions e.g. using pgfplots or datavisualization.

Comment: Can you make it simple by editing my code; which is a part of a large diagram, and I do not want to complicate it. For example editing the circle code to draw a line instead of a circle.

Comment: @Hany You only need to paste my code into your document and load the libraries. I am not sure I understand your request.

Comment: Can this code (which is a node inside a \draw command) be edited to draw a line (with a specific angle and length) instead of drawing a circle: (node [xshift=1cm, yshift=0cm, circle, draw, green, scale=0.8]{})

Comment: @Hany Sorry, I do not understand the question. (Of course you can draw a line with a specific angle and length. If you use `path picture`, anything will be cut off at the boundary of the node.)

Comment: I do not want to cut off at the boundary of the node. I want to draw a line inside the node

Comment: @Hany I was describing what `path picture` does. The only thing one needs to do is to make the node large enough. If I understood your question "Can this code (which is a node inside a \draw command) be edited to draw a line (with a specific angle and length) instead of drawing a circle: (node [xshift=1cm, yshift=0cm, circle, draw, green, scale=0.8]{})" I would be happy trying to answer it...

Comment: I appreciate very much your effort, you answered my need in your answer in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438000/how-to-draw-a-latex-arrow-inside-a-node