# How to draw a -latex arrow inside a node

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using the following code, I draw a line and a -latex arrow in 2 different `\draw` commands. Is it possible to incorporate the -latex code inside the node in the `\draw` line instead of drawing it in a separate `\draw` command?

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick, green] (1,1) node [red, xshift=.3cm, yshift=0cm] {} -- +(0:2cm);
\draw [thick,blue, xshift=.5cm, yshift=0cm, -latex] (1,1) -- +(0:.5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When using the code provided by marmot, only the arrow is shown in a horizontal line but not in a vertical line. What is wrong?

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw [thick, blue, densely dashed] (1,.8) node [minimum width=2cm, xshift=0cm, yshift=.4cm,path picture={\draw [very thick, solid, red, xshift=0cm, yshift=.2cm, -latex'] (0,0) -- +(90:.8cm);}] {} -- +(90:.9cm);
\draw [thick, blue, densely dashed] (1,.8) node [minimum width=2cm, xshift=.36cm, yshift=0cm,path picture={\draw [very thick, solid, red, xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm, -latex'] (0,0) -- +(0:.6cm);}] {} -- +(0:1.56cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with `path picture`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{}
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick, green] (1,1) node [minimum width=1cm,red, xshift=.3cm, yshift=0cm,path picture={
\draw [thick,blue, xshift=.5cm, yshift=0cm, -latex] (0,0) -- +(0:.5cm);}] {} -- +(0:2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When applying your code it works with the horizontal line, but not with the vertical line. I included the code in my question. What is wrong

Comment: @Hany You did everything correct except for `minimum width`, which has to become `minimum height` in the vertical node. Explanation: nodes come by default with some size, and everything within the `path picture` that exceeds that size gets cut. That's why I put `minimum width` in the horizontal node. If you want a universal key, use `minimum size=2cm`.

Comment: I appreciate very much your effort. You answered my question.